# CakePHP redirect to current page after login

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I am triying to redirect to the current page after sucessfull login, but it seems that I am facing too many redirects...
My UsersController is working under a prefix 'admin' and I think it's the root cause but I didn't manage to get this work.

```
Router::prefix('Admin', function(RouteBuilder $builder)
{
   $builder->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'index']);
   $builder->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
});
```

My function initialize in appController looks like this

```
public function initialize()
{ 
    parent::initialize();
    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
    $this->loadComponent('Flash');
    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'loginAction' => [
            'controller' => 'Users',
            'action' => 'login',
            'prefix' => 'admin'
        ],
        'unauthorizedRedirect' => $this->referer(),
        'logoutRedirect'       => [
                'controller' => 'Users',
                'action'     => 'login',
                'prefix' => 'admin'
        ]
    ]);
}
```

and here if action login

```
public function login()
{
    $this->request->allowMethod(['get', 'post']);
    $result = $this->Authentication->getResult();

    if ($result->isValid()) 
    {
        return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
    }

    // display error if user submitted and authentication failed
    if ($this->getRequest()->is("post") && !$result->isValid())
    {
        $this->Flash->error('Email ou mot de passe incorrect.');
    }

    $this->viewBuilder()->setLayout('AdminTheme.login');
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is at the first if block:

```
if ($result->isValid()) 
    {
        //This is the problem
        return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl()); 
    }
```

I believe you mean to pass  `$this->request->referer()` to the `redirect` method instead of `$this->Auth->redirectUrl()`. The referer is the previous url.

Answer (score 0):

I used the function getLoginRedirect(), which seems to be working.

```
if ($result->isValid()) 
    {
        $target = $this->Authentication->getLoginRedirect() ?? '/';
        return $this->redirect($target);
    }
```